Attachments in XSLT1.0
I have a question regarding attachments in xslt1.0. we have a CSV file where data is uploaded and xslt is used to fetch it and produce cXML. But we cannot insert attachment in CSV file.
Is there any way we can insert attachment in CSV file and that will get fetch in xslt. Do we have any code for that.!

I don't think you can use XSLT 1.0 to produce XML from a CSV file. Please provide a [mcve] showing showing an example of the input, your current stylesheet and the expected output.
